# Why does me.com always redirect to Find My iPhone?

Tags: icloud, email, apple-id

I changed my Apple ID, and I have to confirm my old mail @me.com to my new id. But the https://www.me.com/mail/ will always redirect to "find my phone" (maybe some issue with my last iPod touch that was stolen).

Now, how can I access my mail in me.com to confirm for my new ID? Or, why it's redirecting?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you migrated your MobileMe email to iCloud and you can only log into http://me.com to access the few things that remain. So, try getting your mail at https://www.icloud.com/

If you didn't migrate things, you may have to open a support ticket with Apple to have them look at your account. You can always try logging into the same URL from a new computer or clear cookies, caches in the browser in case it's something that isn't clean on the client side, but in all likelihood, the problem is on the server end and the application on the web server believes you don't have mail any more for your logged in account.

Comment: bmike has it right, you need to access everything else on iCloud.com

Comment: Oh man - Stu - thanks for pointing that out. I should have lead with that, not depend on your assist in a comment. +1 and a half.